# Serializing an NSDictionary to XML File

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I have a dictionary containing the necessary info that needs to be sent to a web service for validation.  However I must follow the format provided by the service.

I create the XML structure like

```
NSData * = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:myDictionary options:0 error:0];
NSString *postData [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF*StringEncoding];
```

When pring postData to the cosole, I have all the information I need wrapped inside a

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        my data structure
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

How can I remove the `DOCTYPE` declaration, and `plist` and `dict` elements?

Comment: It's not XML anymore if you remove (both) the `<plist>` and `<dict>`.

Comment: @KennyTM Yes it is, where is says my "data structure," is the XML structure that I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at that point it will be simpler to do a custom serialization...

```
for (id key in dictionary)
{
    [someMutableString appendFormat:@"%@ = %@\n",key,[dictionary objectForKey:key]]];
}
```